# Current display device and customization issue

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using Rstudio on Mac OS and want to customize the interactive display devices, in particular the default font. My understanding is if I use `options("device")`:

```
> options("device")
[1] "RStudioGD"
```

I am expecting the **default** interactive display device to be **quartz**, but it doesn't appear so. And my customization command:

```
quartz.options(family="...")
```

doesn't appear to work either. Any idea?

Comment: what are you trying in place of `...`? allso, it's "device" not "devices", `options('device')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @rawr's comment, at my setup (OSX 10.8.4 & RStudio 0.98.501) the correct command gives:

```
> options("device")
$device
[1] "RStudioGD"
```

If you want to change the default font, you can do that via the preferences menu in RStudio:

`cmd`+`,` => `appearance` => select the desired font

---

UPDATE:

When you want to control the appearance of the text in your plot, I would advise you to use the `ggplot2` package. An example:

```
# creating some example data
df <- data.frame(Xx=1:10,Yy=1:10,Zz=rep(letters[1:2]))

# creating the plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Xx, y=Yy, fill=Zz)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(family="Arial", face="bold", color="#CC6600", size=16),
        axis.text=element_text(family="Times", face="italic", color="blue", size=14),
        legend.title=element_text(family="Courier", face="bold.italic", color="darkgrey", size=18, angle=45))
```

which results in:
[image]

Use `?element_text` to see which parameters of the text you are able to manipulate.

Comment: My bad, I have erroneously put extra 's' to the end of device. The output is correct now (same as yours). The font I am trying to change is not for the console or code editing. It is graphics font when you do: `plot(1:10, 1:10)`.